# Parabolic equation with domain depending on time

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Let $d_1(t)$ and $d_2(t)$ be smooth functions from $[0,T]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $L$ is a uniform elliptic operator and $u :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we consider the problem
\begin{equation}
\left\{\hspace{5pt}\begin{aligned}
&\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} - Lu = f(x,t)& \hspace{10pt} &\text{for $(x,t) \in \big(d_1(t),d_2(t)\big) \times (0,T]$}
;\\
&u(x,0) = g(x) & \hspace{10pt} &\text{for $\lambda \in \big(\lambda_1(T),\lambda_2(T)\big)$.}\\
&u(d_1(t),t) = p(t) & \hspace{10pt} &\text{for $t \in [0,T]$.}\\
&u(d_2(t),t) = q(t)   & \hspace{10pt} &\text{for $t \in [0,T]$.}
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
Here $f,g,p,q$ are some suitable functions.

Do we have some books or papers discussing some kinds of problems like this? I would like to have some existence and regularity results for this. I think it is a parabolic equation with domain depending on time. I have searched for "parabolic equation, time depending domain", "parabolic equation, moving boundary". But I do not have any result.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/9/7/749/pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiH5IW_9ODzAhWRyqQKHYx6AiQQFnoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2wdBDkth84leprJNHPc77Q

Comment: If you're looking for the 1d relativistic boundary condition Schrödinger equation, I think you can solve with the usual eigenbasis functions (depending on time) decomposition. The time derivative of the eigenfunctions seem to be orthogonalizable to the eigenbasis functions. But I don't have the complete calculations for an answer.